# SteamSocket TCP to check for device connectivity

Tags: c#, tcp, uwp, windowsiot

I am using 'StreamSocket' 'Tcp' connection to communicate between my host and client devices on Windows IoT Core. Currently I am using polling every second to check for connectivity status of client devices. I would like to know if there is any better and efficient way of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no better way to do that. There are two ways of detect StreamSocket disconnect:

- send heartbeat message to monitor if the other side(server) is closed.
- read 0-length  means end of the stream.

In addition, you can detect the network connection via [NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation#Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged).By this, the app is able to know if the network is invalid, as the main reason causes the StreamSocket disconnected. More information please see [Reacting to network status changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh465399(v=win.10)#react).

If you change the host as server, all of your device as a client which connected to your host, you can start listening a tcp port via **[StreamSocketListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener)**. The event **[ConnectionReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener.connectionreceived)** could detect the connection incoming and status changed.

```
        StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();
        listener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnection;


    private async void OnConnection(
        StreamSocketListener sender, 
        StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Read first 4 bytes (length of the subsequent string).
                uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
                if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                    //Detect disconnection
                    return;
                }

                // Read the string.
                uint stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
                uint actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLength);
                if (stringLength != actualStringLength)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    //Detect disconnection
                    return;
                }

                //TO DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
             //TO DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

Comment: Detecting ungraceful disconnections is really one of the most annoying things ever to code for.

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT Thanks.

Comment: @NPras do you have any suggestion to handle it?

Comment: To quote this [oft-referenced article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html): *broken connections can only be detected by sending data*. Your heartbeat/keepalive method (and catching all the different ways it can fail) is usually the way to go.